# directive not working in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the controller bound to the index file and i could fetch values from the controller through $scope. All things working as expected except the directives.

I am adding a footer as a directive for my application. For some reason it is not working.

**index.html**

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Specials for {{ today | date }}</h1>
        <h2>Appetizers</h2>
        <div class="appetizers row" ng-repeat="appetizer in appetizers">
          <div class="item col-md-9">
            <h3 class="name">{{appetizer.name}} </h3>
            <p class="description"> {{appetizer.description}}</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <h3> footer</h3>
           <pizza-footer></pizza-footer>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS Code**

```
var app = angular.module('PizzaApp',[]);

    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.today = new Date();

      $scope.appetizers = [
        {
          name: 'Caprese',
          description: 'Mozzarella, tomatoes, basil, balsmaic glaze.',
          price: 4.95
        },
        {
          name: 'Mozzarella Sticks',
          description: 'Served with marinara sauce.',
          price: 3.95
        },
        {
          name: 'Bruschetta',
          description: 'Grilled bread garlic, tomatoes, olive oil.',
          price: 4.95
        }

      ];
    }]);

    app.directive('pizzafooter', function(){
       return {
            restrict:'E',
            templateUrl: 'pizzafooter.html'

        };
     });

    console.log("pizza footer js called");
```

I have the code at :
[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wvodv2cbeKfgQb2WfrcF?p=preview)

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the directive name to `pizzaFooter` as

```
app.directive('pizzaFooter', function(){
```

[UPDATED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/m56BDjEzjfSqNdIVD7kR?p=preview)

`<pizza-footer></pizza-footer>` should match with directive name to `pizzaFooter`

see the angular directive naming conventions.

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.
> For example, the following forms are all equivalent and match the ngBind directive:

[DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)